# How do I create a new df by replace the df ID# with names of another df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have to DFs one contains just ID# and the other is a more comprehensive DF with names, salary, ages and ID#'s

df1 looks like this

```
Name           Salary     ID     Age   City 
Sam            52000      542       52    NYC
Bob            15000      451       21    LA
Sam            72000      556       21    SF
```

where df 2 looks like this with the ID#

```
 Index     1     2   3     4    
 a         542  352  581   521   
 b         451  215  556   451   
 c         540  332  511   121   
 d         451  515  156   951
```

Note some of the ID# reap and that is expected

How do get df2 but just replacing them with the names (and some do repeat I do not want to drop them)

My goal was to have a new df3 where it looked like this

df3

```
Index     1    2     3       4
 a        Sam  Bill  Le     Sam
 b        Mike Jane  Kevin  Le
 c        Jame Kerry David  Mike
 d        Andy Steve Jane   Andy
```

(note my examples id# does not match the names please forgive me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fist build a lookup dict and then use applymap

```
name_map = df.set_index('ID')['Name'].to_dict()
df2.applymap(name_map.get)

    1       2       3       4
0   Sam     None    None    None
1   Bob     None    Sam     Bob
2   None    None    None    None
3   Bob     None    None    None
```